# How can a create a connection between two KVM private network?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, opennebula

I have two KVM node. In both sever there is a bridge connection for the interface prv1 with network 192.168.15.0/28 and in other KVM node there is a bridge connection for the interface prv1 with network 192.168.15.16/28 . I can create a VM from both interface. But, how can I make a connection so that 192.168.15.0/28 network  can be reachable to 192.168.15.16/28 ?

Below is my network diagram in which I want access between VM1 and VM2.
Any guide will be appreciate.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLbFo.png)

Comment: Stop now. Do not use other organization's public IP addresses as your own, not even on a private network. This can cause a variety of connectivity problems. Use actual private IP addresses instead.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHampton, these both KVM are mine. So, these host are purchase from hetzner. There network works like that .

Comment: You are trying to use IP addresses that belong to Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry, which IP?

Comment: 20.20.15.0/28 and 20.20.15.16/28 are Microsoft IP addresses. They are not private addresses and should not be used as such.

Comment: But private IP can be used any right? I can change that Ip no worry. These IP are also not publicly accessible.

Comment: I have change this IP

Comment: @NibaTandukar no, you can't just use any IPs for private purposes. Even if they don't accessible from the Internet right now it's still a bad idea to have them on your nodes. There are many things that will/might happen this way. There are a special reserved IP ranges for private subnets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: sorry I was unaware of this .

Comment: @NStorm and I have changed this  IP to 192.168.15.0/28 and 192.168.15.16.0/28

Comment: Ok, now, please update the pictures and text in the question for us to talk about your actual IP addresses. And then there are couple of ways to do that.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I have change the Ip address

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking for. Your diagrams shows VMs are actually having IPs from the 10.10.15.X range which you aren't mentioning in your question. Besides you didn't told if the prv1 interfaces from both nodes are physically connected to each other.

Do you need a connection for VMs or for the bridges prv1 on the physical nodes? If later, you will a router of some sort between those 2 subnetworks or a *dirty hack* with `onlink` routes providing you really have physical connection between prv1 interfaces on your hosts (physical nodes).

I might update my answer once you will update your question to make it more obvious what you require to achieve.

Comment: Hi , I have just updated my diagram above. It is  20.20.15.X not 10.10.15.X. Both the prv1 are the bridge connection in the node. These  bridge connection are virtual network for KVM. Also these both the bridge connection have vlan of 4001.

Comment: @NibaTandukar first of all you aren't inserting your image correctly. Please use an "Image" button and don't remove any square brackets it adds. Second it's still not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I want a connection between both  the bridges prv1. So that all the VMs created through that bridges connection  can access each other.Is the image still not visible?

Comment: @NibaTandukar you didn't answered my questions I've had previously. Like if you have a physical connections between prv1 on nodeA and nodeB. And about connection between VM1 and VM2.

Comment: No, there is no physical connection between prv1 NodeA and NodeB @NStorm. It is virtual network for bridge only.

Comment: @NibaTandukar then what's your physical connection path between those? How do suppose to route then? Through the public IPs? Do you need a connections between VMs or physical nodes?

Comment: So, here the gateway for these private network is the public IP of these KVM node.ie 5.9.xx.xx for one prv1 and for other 188.44.xx.xx

Comment: @NibaTandukar do you mean that only physical connection between NODE1 and NODE2 are through public IPs?

Comment: Yes @NStorm. But the server provider has give vlan for the private virtual network.

Comment: @NibaTandukar then you have to create that VLAN sub-interface on your physical interface. Like if your physical NIC are eth0, you can use your distro tools to add a eth0.4001 interface (which is VLAN-aware). Then you can bridge it to prv1 bridge and that will make both bridges are switched through VLAN 4001.

Comment: I have also configure Vlan for both interfaces. Here is my configuration

[root@CentOS-79-64-minimal network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eno1.4001 

DEVICE=eno1.4001

BOOTPROTO=none

ONBOOT=yes


BRIDGE=prv1

[root@CentOS-79-64-minimal network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-prv1

DEVICE="prv1"
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
IPADDR=192.168.15.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
GATEWAY=5.9.xx.xx
BROADCAST=192.168.15.15
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
STP=off
DELAY=0
VLAN=yes
ZONE=internal

Comment: what am I missing ? I am unable to find. Is this configuration correct?